# CRM 2016 Toolkit for Visual Studio

Tags: dynamics-crm

I can't find CRM 2016 Toolkit for Visual Studio and CRM Developer Extension do not support CRM 2016(I have tried and it fails).

Anyone know what's going on?

Best regards

Knut Myre

Answer (score 1):

The toolkit is no longer offered in the SDK.  It had a lot of problems anyway.  Check out the excellent open source alternative, [CRM Developer Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f9ab063-acec-4c55-bd6c-5eb7c6cffec4).

Comment: I use it for 2016 web resources, the other tools should work for 2016 as well. Did you try it out?

Comment: I've been using it for CRM 2016 a lot lately and it's working fine. The tool is updated very regularly.